# Select XML data from column except certain values T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(XMLValue XML);

INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES
       (
       '<Root>
  <row>
    <VendorPlantName>Plant 1</VendorPlantName>
    <TotalAttainableUnits>3693</TotalAttainableUnits>
  </row>
  <row>
    <VendorPlantName>Plant 2</VendorPlantName>
    <TotalAttainableUnits>69477</TotalAttainableUnits>
  </row>
  <row>
    <VendorPlantName>Plant 3</VendorPlantName>
    <TotalAttainableUnits>573</TotalAttainableUnits>
  </row>
  </Root>'
       );

CREATE TABLE #Table2
(NodeName  NVARCHAR(255)
,NodeValue NVARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO #table2
VALUES
       (
       'VendorPlantName','Plant 2'
       ),
       (
       'VendorPlantName','Plant 1'
       );
```

With those 2 tables, is it possible, within reason of course, to produce the following output.

```
<Root>
  <row>
    <VendorPlantName>Plant 3</VendorPlantName>
    <TotalAttainableUnits>573</TotalAttainableUnits>
  </row>
<Root>
```

More detail.  The XML with be completely dynamic.  The nodename and the values will be unknown as well.  Is it possible (using SQL serve 2008 R2) to select only the nodes and values from the xml document that don't appear in the second table.

The use case is only return nodenames and values that haven't been seen before.  This would be lots easier as a dynamic sql query with some joins, but I can't do that.  Any help is appreciated.  Even if the answer is find another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what *"The XML will be completely dynamic"* really means. As it looks, there will always be the `<Root>` and a lot of `<row>` elements. So the dynamic part is the unknown field list within each `<row>`. Correct?

You might try something along this:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE(XMLValue XML);

INSERT INTO @tbl1
VALUES
       (
       '<Root>
  <row>
    <VendorPlantName>Plant 1</VendorPlantName>
    <TotalAttainableUnits>3693</TotalAttainableUnits>
  </row>
  <row>
    <VendorPlantName>Plant 2</VendorPlantName>
    <TotalAttainableUnits>69477</TotalAttainableUnits>
  </row>
  <row>
    <VendorPlantName>Plant 3</VendorPlantName>
    <TotalAttainableUnits>573</TotalAttainableUnits>
  </row>
  </Root>'
       );

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(NodeName  NVARCHAR(255)
                   ,NodeValue NVARCHAR(255)
                    );

INSERT INTO @tbl2
VALUES
       (
       'VendorPlantName','Plant 2'
       ),
       (
       'VendorPlantName','Plant 1'
       );
```

--The cte creates the *exclude list*

```
WITH ExcludeFields(ExclFld) AS
(
    SELECT NodeName AS [@nn]
          ,NodeValue AS [@nv] 
    FROM @tbl2 t2
    FOR XML PATH('exclFld'),TYPE
)
SELECT Combined.query('
                      <Root> 
                      { 
                          for $rw in /row
                          return 
                          <row>
                          {
                            for $fld in $rw/*
                            return
                            if(/exclFld[@nn=local-name($fld)]/@nv=$fld/text()) then
                            <x/>
                            else
                            $fld
                          }
                          </row>
                      }
                      </Root>
                      ')
               .query('/Root/row[empty(x)]')

FROM ExcludeFields ef
CROSS JOIN @tbl1 t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ef.ExclFld AS [*]
                  ,t1.XMLValue.query('/Root/row')
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE) A(Combined);
```

The idea in short:

We create an intermediate XML containing your rows and the list of exclude fields:

```
<exclFld nn="VendorPlantName" nv="Plant 2" />
<exclFld nn="VendorPlantName" nv="Plant 1" />
<row>
  <VendorPlantName>Plant 1</VendorPlantName>
  <TotalAttainableUnits>3693</TotalAttainableUnits>
</row>
<row>
  <VendorPlantName>Plant 2</VendorPlantName>
  <TotalAttainableUnits>69477</TotalAttainableUnits>
</row>
<row>
  <VendorPlantName>Plant 3</VendorPlantName>
  <TotalAttainableUnits>573</TotalAttainableUnits>
</row>
```

No we can use an XQuery-FLWOR approach to run through each row and then through each field and return a `<x/>` if the combination of node-name and node-value exists in the list of exclude fields.

With this XML we can run another XQuery getting just the rows where there is no `<x>`.

### Another approach

...You can shred this and use *standard SQL* for the hard work:

```
WITH TheRows AS
(          
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.rw) AS RowNumber
          ,rw.query('.') TheRow
    FROM @tbl1 t1
    CROSS APPLY t1.XMLValue.nodes('/Root/row') A(rw)
)
,EAV AS
(
    SELECT r.RowNumber
          ,fld.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(1000)') AS FieldName
          ,fld.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(1000)') AS FieldValue 
    FROM TheRows r
    CROSS APPLY r.TheRow.nodes('row/*') Each(fld)
)
,SkipRows AS
(
    SELECT EAV.RowNumber
    FROM EAV
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl2 t2 WHERE t2.NodeName=EAV.FieldName AND t2.NodeValue=EAV.FieldValue)
    GROUP BY EAV.RowNumber
)
SELECT *
FROM EAV
WHERE EAV.RowNumber NOT IN (SELECT sr.RowNumber FROM SkipRows sr);
```

The last result can easily be returned as XML - if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers.

Comment: @DaytonBrown I'm glad to help you. Just for my curiosity: Which approach is better for you? Did you run them for performance comparisson?

Comment: We badly missing XQuery 3.1 implementation in MS SQL Server.

Comment: @Shnugo, I sent you a LinkedIn invite to connect few days ago. Let's connect.

Comment: I'm most likely going to use the sql shred version.  And performance shouldn't be much of an issue.  The XML docs won't be that large, nor will it be running a large quantity of them.